# Stilistisch in Ordnung, jedesmal das Subjekt zu nennen?

Tags: style

Ist es stilistisch gesehen in Ordnung, wenn ich in jedem Satz, den ich schreibe, das Subjekt auch erwähne?

Zum Beispiel:

> Gestern bin ich mit dem Bus gefahren(,) und ich schaute dabei aus dem
>   Fenster. Plötzlich hielt der Bus vor einer roten Ampel an(,) und er bremste sehr stark.

Wäre es nicht eleganter, wenn ich auch mal das Subjekt weglassen würde?

> Gestern bin ich mit dem Bus gefahren(,) und schaute dabei aus dem
>   Fenster. Plötzlich hielt der Bus vor einer roten Ampel an(,) und bremste
>   sehr stark.

Die Klammern habe ich nur gesetzt, um auszudrücken, dass es jeweils zwei Hauptsätze sind.

Also wie ist das stilistisch? Sollte ich, wenn ich längere Texte schreibe, ab und zu das Subjekt weglassen, wenn es implizit klar ist, wer das Subjekt ist?

Comment: Du kannst z.B. nur *der* statt *der Bus* schreiben. Das wird verstanden und ist ein Fingerzeig auf das Subjekt. Besser als es zu wiederholen. Das *ich* im zweiten Hauptsatz und das *er* im vierten Hauptsatz solltest du einfach weglassen.

Comment: Mich lenkt das so ab, dass der Bus erst hält und dann bremst … :D

Comment: Das kommt alles drauf an, wo diese Sätze verwendet werden. Wie ist der Sprachduktus davor, wie ist er danach? Wer liest den Text? Und so weiter.

Answer (score 3):

- Kurze Antwort: wer mag. (Bezogen auf den Fragetitel)
- Kurze Antwort: ja. (Bezogen auf die Fragen im Text)

Jedenfalls unter der Annahme, dass der Leserschaft zugetraut wird, Bezüge zu vorhergehenden Sätzen richtig herzustellen. (Und dass es *nicht* der eigene / gewollte Stil ist, das Subjekt immer und überall auszuschreiben.)

aus

> Gestern bin ich mit dem Bus gefahren und ich schaute dabei aus dem Fenster. Plötzlich hielt der Bus vor einer roten Ampel an und [d]er [Bus] bremste sehr stark.

kann in kürzer/ flüssiger so lauten:

> Gestern bin ich mit dem Bus gefahren und schaute dabei aus dem Fenster. Plötzlich hielt er vor einer roten Ampel an und bremste sehr stark.

Da mein Argument der Lesefluss: Kausalitäten bzw. zeitliche Abfolgen beachten kann diesen erhöhen:

> [...] Plötzlich bremste er stark und hielt vor einer roten Ampel.

Denn erst anzuhalten und dann bremsen = Knoten im Kopf, hier aufgrund des bekannten Zusammenhangs schnell gelöst.

Es kann jedoch vorkommen, dass ein vorhergehender Satz Objekte enthält, auf die danach Bezug genommen werden könnte - hier ist für eine bessere Zuordnung in Folgesätzen das Subjekt hilfreich.

> Haus öffnen, durchgehen, alle Fenster und Türen öffnen, Durchzug abwarten. Schließen und weggehen.

Das ist mehr eine kurze Anweisung als ein Romanzitat. Dennoch bleibt unklar: Fenster und Türen schließen oder nur oder auch das Haus schließen?

Comment: Über das erst Anhalten und dann Bremsen bin ich auch zu allererst gestolpert.

Answer (score 1):

Stilistisch ist es in dem Fall besser, das Subjekt nochmals zu erwähnen, da beim Ersetzen mit "er", nicht wirklich klar ist, wer oder was gemeint ist.

Ich als Muttersprachler würde den Satz so schreiben:

> Gestern bin ich mit dem Bus gefahren und während ich aus dem Fenster schaute hielt plötzlich der Bus vor einer roten Ampel an und bremste sehr stark.

Als Faustregel gilt: wenn der Kontext klar ist, ist weniger im Deutschen meist mehr.

Beim Satz

> Haus öffnen, durchgehen, alle Fenster und Türen öffnen, Durchzug abwarten. Schließen und weggehen.

ist für mich der Kontext klar; das geht so.

Comment: Welcher andere "er" als dem Bus kann plötzlich anhalten? Da der Satz aus ich-Perspetikve geschrieben ist und ich vom Frager keinen anderen Kontext außer dem zweisatzigen Beispiel lese, müsste jedes andere "er" ein hier unbekannter Dritter sein. Bei `Haus öffnen...` sehe ich mehrdeutigen Kontext und es ist kein Beispiel von der Fragerin = Bezug zur Frage _nur_ durch meine Antwort gegeben = ungünstiger Bezug ohne weiter Erläuterung => entweder Bezug herstellen oder Frage ohne Querverweis auf andere Antworten beachten.

Comment: Ein anderer "Er" wäre eben ein unbekannter oder aus einem vorherigen Gespräch und/oder Satz bekannter Dritter. Bei Haus öffnen... ist es nicht eindeutig klar, aber dennoch verständlich, was gemeint ist. Es ist eben oft immer eine Wahl zwischen Präzision und Pedanterie.

Comment: Da das aus der Frage _nicht_ hervorgeht, nur diese beantworten.